# If $x^2 < y^2$, $x, y \in \Bbb{N}$, then $x < y$.

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification

It suffices to show the contrapositive: If $x > y$, then $x^2 > y^2$.

$x > y$ suggests a positive difference between x and y — that is, $x - y = s > 0$.

Then, we must show the difference increases when multiplied, or $s < s*s$.

The above is $s*1 < s*s$. Then $s^{-1}s < s^{-1}s*s \Longrightarrow 1 < s$ by property of multiplicative inverses.

---

The above is my attempt at a proof, but it fails when $s = 1$. Indeed, the difference doesn't grow (because $1^2 = 1$).

Is this strategy at solving a proof busted, and why?

I've tried an alternative proof.

---

It suffices to show the difference between $x^2$ and $y^2$ is greater than the difference between $x$ and $y$.

$x^2 - y^2 = (x + y)(x - y)$ by distribution.

Is $(x + y)(x - y) > (x - y)$? By simplifying using the multiplicative inverse law (since $x - y \neq 0$), we find that is true only if $x + y > 1$, which is certainly true. $\blacksquare$

---

Is the second proof valid?

Comment: you can show $x^2=y^2+N$ with $N$ integer, so that $x^2\ge y^2$. You do not need strinct inequality, inverse of $<$ is $\ge$.

Comment: The function square is monotone increasing for $x>0$

Comment: @Gio I get confused by the convention around *monotone* and *monotonic*.  Is monotone increasing equivalent to strictly increasing, or is monontone increasing equivalent to never decreasing?

Comment: @user2661923 strictly increasing